# All my pages apart from index lead to a 404 page

Tags: wordpress

My settings for permalinks: **default : /?p=123** works but if I switch to **by post name**  All pages stop working and just go to a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your permalink settings and see if you have enable rewriting in your .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```